# how to plot stock dally bar chart with MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I was trying to plot dally bar chart like this with MATLAB but I'm so confusing.

[image]

I appreciate any help.

P.S. : I do my best

```
[Price time]=xlsread('one_year.xlsx');
formatIn='mm/dd/yyyy';
t=flipud(datenum(time,formatIn));
dates=linspace(t(1),t(end),13);
plot(t,flipud(Price))
%Set Ticks
labels = datestr(dates,3);
set(gca, 'XTick', dates);
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', labels);
Xlabels = linspace(min(Price),max(Price),6);
X = linspace(min(Price),max(Price),6);
set(gca, 'YTick', X);
set(gca, 'YTickLabel', Xlabels);
%Label Axes and Set Title
xlabel('Date')
ylabel('Price')
title('Price of Microsoft')
```

Comment: I have "open price" , "close price" , "high price" and "low price" too for plotting just like that but I don't know how .

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error message? Does the image that Matlab produces not look as expected? If the image doesn't look like you expected, edit your post to include a link to the image and describe the problem. If you are getting an error message, edit the post to include the error.

Comment: At least following your `formatIn` you have one price per day, how do you expect the four different prices to be calculated?

Comment: Dear @Daniel That is my question, How can i add 4 prices and plot just like that ?

Comment: So you already have all four prices calculated? In your code I only see one price.

Comment: Yes @Daniel , I have Excel file with 4 prices , but you are right , I just use one of them, How can i add other 3 prices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [highlow](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/highlow.html) from the financial toolbox creates such plots.